# How the STL implement reverse iterator dereferencing with non-linear data structures?

Tags: c++, c, oop

Pointing is used without the literal meaning of pointers. Take the next paragraph with a grain of salt.

It's easy to implement a reverse iterator, making rbegin() == end() and rend() == begin() with a linear data structure, since you can map the reversed access to the element just BEFORE where the iterator is pointing (rbegin() points to end(), but access end()-1, for example). But when dealing with trees or, in my case, hash tables, how should I handle this mapping? I'm currently using a "OneAfterTheLast" flag to mark the end of a forwarding iteration session, and I'm thinking about manually implementing the reverse iterator logic and adding a "OneBeforeTheFirst" flag also. Is that a good design?

Also, the find() method should return a "OneAfterTheLast"-ed iterator in the case of not finding the key, or should my check method check for both flags (OneAfterTheEnd and OneBeforeTheFirst)?

Here is my public interface, just for reference, still without the reverse iterator methods. Both the container class and the iterator class are opaque.

```
typedef PWError (*PWDictCallback)(const char *key, const char *val, void *extra);
PWError pwdictCreate(PWDict **dictRef, PWDictImplementationId id, size_t elements);
PWError pwdictCreateWithImplementation(PWDict **dictRef, const PWDictImplementation* impl, size_t elements);
void pwdictDestroy(PWDict *dict);
unsigned int pwdictSize(const PWDict *dict);
unsigned long pwdictSizeInBytes(const PWDict *dict);
PWError pwdictGet(const PWDict *dict, const char *key, char *output, size_t size);
PWError pwdictSet(PWDict *dict, const char *key, const char *value);
PWError pwdictRemove(PWDict *dict, const char *key);
PWError pwdictIteratorCreate(PWDictIterator **itRef, PWDict *dict);
PWError pwdictIteratorBegin(PWDictIterator *it);
int pwdictIteratorIsEnd(PWDictIterator *it);
void pwdictIteratorDestroy(PWDictIterator *it);
PWError pwdictFind(PWDictIterator *it, const char *key);
const char *pwdictIteratorGetKey(const PWDictIterator *it);
const char *pwdictIteratorGetValue(const PWDictIterator *it);
PWError pwdictIteratorSetValue(PWDictIterator *it, const char *value);
PWError pwdictIteratorRemove(PWDictIterator *it);
PWError pwdictIteratorNext(PWDictIterator *it);
PWError pwdictClear(PWDict *dict);
PWError pwdictAdd(PWDict *dict, const PWDict *from);
int pwdictIsEqual(const PWDict *d1, const PWDict *d2);
PWError pwdictForeach(PWDict *dict, PWDictCallback cb, void *extra);
void pwdictPrint(const PWDict *dict, int logLevel);
```

Comment: Note that the standard doesn't require all containers to be reversible. In particular, the unordered containers in C++11 standard (such as `unordered_map`, which is basically a hash table) are only required to support forward iterators, and so are not required to be reversible.

Comment: That adds GREATLY to the matter. Unfortunately, the project requires bidirectional iterators, so I thought it would be good to support reserve iterators also.

Comment: Once you have a bidirectional iterator, you've implemented the basic functionality needed by `reverse_iterator`. In fact, you should just be able to use `std::reverse_iterator<>` to provide your container's reverse iterator.

Comment: I'm not working with C++, so that's not possible.

Comment: I see - that wasn't clear to me from the question, but it explains the very C-like interface declarations you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C++03 standard:

> The fundamental relation between a reverse iterator and its corresponding iterator i is established by the identity: `&*(reverse_iterator(i)) == &*(i - 1)`.
>
> This mapping is dictated by the fact that while there is always a pointer past the end of an array, there might not be a valid pointer before the beginning of an array.

(the second sentence was removed from the C++11 standard)

The way a reverse iterator is typically implemented is that internally there's a normal iterator for the container that points to the element *after* the item the reverse iterator logically refers to.  That way, the internal iterator (which can be obtained using `reverse_iterator::base()`) always points within the container or to the container's end. So it's always valid. When dereferencing the reverse iterator, you simply decrement the base (which can be done if you have a bidirectional iterator) and dereference that.

I'll assume you have a working bidirectional iterator in your interface since you mention that that's part of your requirements. So, I'll assume there's a `pwdictIteratorPrev()` function.  Also, the reverse iterator functionality has a need to temporarily manipulate a private iterator, so I also assume there's a couple more bits of functionality, such as the ability to copy an iterator and the ability to compare iterators.

So these functions (whether in the public interface or not) should be available. I believe they can probably be easily written:

```
int pwdictIteratorIsEqual(PWDictIterator* it1, PWDictIterator* it2);
PWError pwdictIteratorCopy(PWDictIterator* dst, PWDictIterator const* src);
PWError pwdictIteratorEnd(PWDictIterator* it);
```

Your reverse iterator could look something like the following (no error handling shown):

```
struct PWDictRIterator {
    PWDictIterator* base;
    PwDict* dict;
};

typdef struct PWDictRIterator PWDictRIterator;

PWError pwdictRIteratorCreate(PWDictRIterator **ritRef, PWDict *dict)
{
    PWError err;

    PWDictRIterator* riter = malloc(sizeof(PWDictRIterator));  // or however you want to allocate

    if (riter) {
        riter->dict = dict;
        err = pwdictIteratorCreate( &riter->base, dict);
    }

    return err;
}

PWError pwdictRIteratorBegin(PWDictRIterator *rit)
{
    return pwdictIteratorEnd(rit->base);
}

int pwdictRIteratorIsEnd(PWDictRIterator *rit)
{
    PWDictIterator* begin;

    PWError err;
    err = pwdictIteratorCreate( &begin, rit->dict);
    err = pwdictIteratorBegin(&begin);

    // there needs to be some way to do the following somehow - 
    //  I assume a plain old pointer compare won't do the trick
    int is_end = pwdictIteratorIsEqual( rit->base, begin);

    pwdictIteratorDestroy(begin);

    return is_end;
}


const char* pwdictRIteratorGetKey(onst PWDictRIterator *rit)
{
    // remember - to 'derefernce' a reverse iterator, we have to
    //  decrement the base first

    PWDictIterator* tmp;

    // all error handling elided...
    PWError err;
    err = pwdictIteratorCreate( &tmp, rit->dict);

    // we need a temporary iterator, so the base can stay the same
    //  I assume that some sort of copy operation can be created
    //  for iterators - it might not need to be part of the public interface
    err = pwdictIteratorCopy(tmp,rit->base);   

    err = pwdictIteratorPrev(tmp);

    const char* result = pwdictIteratorGetKey(tmp);

    pwdictIteratorDestroy(tmp);

    return result;
}


PWError pwdictRIteratorNext(PWDictRIterator *rit)
{
    return pwdictIteratorPrev(rit->base);
}

PWError pwdictRIteratorPrev(PWDictRIterator *rit)
{
    return pwdictIteratorNext(rit->base);
}

// further functions are basically variations on the above theme...
```

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed! Thanks. I ended up not using composition. Since I'm in C land, I just declared both at the same file, as a single "package", both using the next and prev operators. After that I just needed some states: now I have a common state enum that handles the one before first and one after last logic.
But I'll keep your design on my mind, for future references.

Answer (score 3):

`std::reverse_iterator` does it by holding a normal iterator but (conceptually) returning `*(i-1)` on dereference. You can do the same - or just directly use `std::reverse_iterator`.

Comment: In this case, I would double the complexity of iterating through my container, since I'd need to search for the next element on dereference and also on increment.

Comment: If you're doing a search on increment then you're doing something odd. It's normally an O(1) operation. But if it is expensive enough to matter then the obvious solution is to cache the result.

Comment: I have a hashtable, I need search for the next element in the next non-empty bucket if I'm at the end of the current one. It's not terribly expensive, but it's still duplicated code.

Answer (score 1):

For consistancy with the iterator pattern used everywhere in C++, your rbegin() should create an iterator pointing to the last element (the one before end()) and your rend() should create an iterator pointing to the element-before-the-beginning (one before begin()).

That allows you to use the same logic as a typical iterator for loop:

```
for ([iterator type] i = something.rbegin(); i != rend(); ++i)
```

Your question wasn't very clear.  Consider tidying it up a bit.  I'm not even sure I answered the question you asked

Comment: I'm not using C++ AND there is no one before begin() element, it's not even safe to address it on a simple array (it's granted for arrays that `array + sizeof(array) + 1` is a valid address, but the opposite is not, you could have a 0 segment-addressed array, and array-1 would underflow).

Comment: @Spidey Why then did you tag C++ in your question?  I'll also point out that dereferencing end() causes an error as well, because it doesnt point to anything.  Semantically, it's equivalent to `for (int i = 0; i < array_length; ++i)`.  array[array_length] is not a valid element either.  I also highly highly doubt you'll ever have an array allocated at 0x00000000.

Comment: It's not about dereferencing, it's about being a valid address. The standard explicitly says that for any array statically allocated, the one-after-the-last address is valid.

Comment: I tagged C++ because I guess people with C++ experience would be able to give advice based on the STL implementations.